# Hibernate nested discriminator on inherited classes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, inheritance

I have 2 MYSQL tables

**table1**

```
id     bigint auto increment Primary Key
type   Enum ('vegetable','fruit')
color  Enum ('green','red','yellow')
```

**table2**

```
id     bigint (same as the id in Table 1)
sweet  boolean
sour   boolean
.. other fields specific to type fruit
```

Now I'm creating 3 objects, first the parent class

```
@Entity
@Configurable
@Table(name = "table1")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class ParentClass {
 ..
}
```

Now the second class for vegetable

```
@Entity
@Configurable
@DiscriminatorValue("vegetable")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "color", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Vegetable extends Parent{
 ..
}
```

And thirdly, the fruit class

```
@Entity
@Configurable
@SecondaryTables({ @SecondaryTable(name = "table2",
    pkJoinColumns = { @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id") }) })
@DiscriminatorValue("fruit")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "color", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Fruit extends Parent{
 ..
}
```

I'm needing the second discriminator to add further inherited classes (6 further classes) on Vegetable and Fruit like,

```
@Entity
@Configurable
@DiscriminatorValue("red")
public class RedVegetable extends Vegetable{
..
}

@Entity
@Configurable
@DiscriminatorValue("green")
public class GreenFruit extends Fruit{
..
}
```

and so on.

Hibernate isn't letting me do that. What's wrong with my design? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learnt this cannot be done in Hibernate. So found an alternate way to do things by merging the discriminator friends in table1 like Enum ('fruit|red', 'fruit|green', 'vegetable|red'.. & so on). 
Please correct me if I was wrong.